# Multiple Row Images Gallery in Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html

I want to add a multiple row gallery view in jquery for dynamic images on my web page , like the one below.

[image: gallery view]

I m not a css developer , so i want a plugin which can handle most of my css
I have already tried JPages (which works well) but adding textarea within each image doesnot maintain the row shape.
In addition , i have tried gallerific , but it works well when my images are of fixed width and height.

Can anyone suggest a plugin ,which deals with dynamic images(variable sizes) and allow me to customize the cell . i.e i can add html element within the image.

Comment: @Aaru i have used jCarousel .it doesnot multi row images.if you have any demo where they have done that do share a link

Answer (score 1):

Your can refer Jquery Plugin site for your reference.

[Jquery plugins](http://jquery-plugins.net/)

Also you can try to use jquery grid view,so that it allows easy way to produce,[**Jquery Grid**](http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/grid) , [**Freewall**](http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/) , [**Freewall grid**](http://jquery-plugins.net/freewall-dynamic-grid-layout-without-gaps)

If you have any doubt let me know.

[**Pagers for slider**](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/pager.php#adv-custom)

Thanks

Comment: The plugins you are suggesting are only arranging images in a grid. I want proper navigation with the previous and next arrows.Previous and next arrows in your suggested plugins are taking to new pages

Comment: Pagers For Slider is not doing multiple rows.

Comment: You can try Multiple rows carousel: http://www.richardscarrott.co.uk/app/webroot/assets/javascript/jquery/carousel/demo/

Comment: :) I have tried this as well.. it works for fixed width and height. i have chosen the workaround , im cropping my images using thumbnail  plugins available , to fixed width and height.Plugins(Jpages,gallerific) allows dynamic images however addition of html elements distort the container width.

Answer (score 1):

> > use this *http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified*.
> >     Also check its documentation and examples to customize it.